# Метод sum(). Объясните, как работает в данном участке кода

Tags: python, методы

```
print(sum(x in 'уеыаоэяию' for x in 'пара-па-пам'))
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему программа выводит число 4, ведь при проверке получаются True и False. Как метод sum считает в данном случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Python 3.x `True` (при конвертации в число) всегда равно 1, а `False` равно 0.

```
>>> int(False)
0
>>> int(True)
1
```

Во втором питоне обычно так же, но не гарантируется, потому что True и False можно переопределить (в третьем - нельзя).

*PS. Этот код работает в Python 2.x:*

```
False = 3
```

*Но не будет работать в Python 3.x.*

Подробности в [PEP-285](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/).

Comment: Более того, `True == 1`, `False == 0` (хотя `True is not 1`, `False is not 0`)

Comment: Более того,  `int in type(True).__bases__`    даст   `True`  так что возможно там и преобразования то нет.

Answer (score 0):

дело в том, что зачастую `True` считается как 1, откуда имея 4 вхождения, мы имеем 4 истинны, то есть 4 единицы